# Is it possible to run local notifications for ionic 3 if app closed form react apps?

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, ionic3, localnotification

I am developing a hybrid mobile app for Android and IOS by using ionic 3. In my app, want to implement local notifications which trigger for every 2 minutes which is working fine if the app open and not closed in recent apps in both Android and IOS devices. If I closed the recent apps that time I am not able to receive notifications, But my requirement is I should able to receive notifications if I close recent apps

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: refer this  https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-run-app-forever-in-background-like-whatsapp/12546